# Simple software to add/edit/view/remove image metadata (IPTC keywords)

Tags: windows, image-processing, metadata

I have a lot of unorganized family photos. I want to be able to search all images using the standardized IPTC metadata keywords (I assume this is most widely spread way to tag photos and is cross-platform, correct me if I'm wrong).

I have tried several programs but non are what I am looking for. I tried several free programs from [Wikipedia's Comparison of metadata editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_metadata_editors).

I am using words "tag" and "keyword" interchangeably.

Requirements (I would call all of them "straightforward" as there is nothing special in them):

1. Batch select files/folders and apply tag/tags to all files in the selected folders (without overwriting existing tags)
2. click on a folder and have all [distinct] tags visible from all files underneath this folder, including subfolders
3. click any tag from point #2 and rename it so that it got renamed in all files which match the currently selected folder (and not others)
4. delete a tag from point #2 so that it got removed from all affected files which match the currently selected folder
5. enter a tag and have all matching files get listed with a preview/view of some sort
6. Point #5 must be accompanied with a ability to specify logical condition between the tags (AND/OR)
7. Should be runnable on Windows platform
8. tags should be embedded into the file to avoid desynchronization between db and filesystem
9. Freeware is very desirable. But if not, then commercial

Commercial applications may have a different business model. But if we think in "per month subscription" terms, then around 7 USD sounds reasonable. But I would rather have a "focused" app for a lower price than have a powerful app with features I won't use.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Very detailed and specific question, congrats. Just one thing missing: the price limit if it comes to paid solutions :) Could you please specify that?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome :) The price, they all may have a different business model. But if we think in "per month subscription" terms, then around 7 USD sounds reasonable. But I would rather have a "focused" app for a lower price than have a powerful app with features I won't use. You know, for instance, I found "Duplicate Photo Finder" from "FreePictureSolutions" and it does just that, finds duplicates and lets me remove them. Also, "Advanced Renamer". Those kinds of "specialized" apps which do one thing outstanding.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I've integrated that with your question. Note you can always [edit] your posts :) Good luck then!